# How Inner bean is destroyed in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

When a bean is declared inner bean then it should be destroyed with the destruction of Outer bean.But this is not happening in below case where destroy method of bean is not called.

**innerbeans-spring.xml**

```
<bean id="car" name="carBean" class="com.semanticbits.shoaib.innerbeans.Car" destroy-method="destroy" init-method="init">
    <property name="engine">
        <bean class="com.semanticbits.shoaib.innerbeans.Engine" destroy-method="destroy" init-method="init">

        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Car.java**:  Just required code written here

```
 public void init(){
    System.out.println("Car init method");
 }
 public void destroy(){
    System.out.println("Car destroy method");
 }


  public static void main(String[] args){
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context=(ConfigurableApplicationContext)ApplicationContextFactory.getApplicationContext("innerbeans-spring.xml");
    Car car=context.getBean("car",Car.class);
    context.getBeanFactory().destroyBean("car",car);
}
```

**Engine.java** : Just required code written here

```
public void init(){
    System.out.println("Engine init method");
}

public void destroy(){
    System.out.println("Engine destroy method");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Engine init method
Car init method
Car destroy method
```

My question is:

1) `getBeanFactory().destroyBean(String beanName,Object beanReference)`
What does beanName means here?

2)Why `destroy` method of Engine class is not called as Engine is inner bean to Car class??

**Extending the question:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   ConfigurableApplicationContext context=(ConfigurableApplicationContext)ApplicationContextFactory.getApplicationContext("innerbeans-spring.xml");
   Car car=context.getBean("car",Car.class);
   context.getBeanFactory().destroyBean("car",car);
   //now here Car bean is destroy.
   //when I call then check the output section.

   context.getBeanFactory().destroySingletons();


}
```

**Extended Output:**

```
Engine init method
Car init method
Car destroy method
Car destroy method
Engine destroyed.
```

3)When Car instance was already destroyed then why Car's destroy() method called again?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please let me know if additional code is required.

Comment: Since there is no reference to `Engine` bean, doesn't it mean that `Engine` bean destroyed? Garbage will collect any inner class, variable of `Car` bean.

Comment: But then why destroy() method is not called of Engine class

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe the Engine will be destroyed only when the BeanFactory closes.

You could also directly let the Car handle this, by calling the Engine's destroy method:

**Car.java:**

```
public void destroy(){
    engine.destroy();
    System.out.println("Car destroy method");
}
```

Comment: Why to call explicitly engine.destroy()...If outer bean is garbage collected then inner bean should automatically be garbage collected. I am destroying car reference which indirectly should destroy engine thus calling destroy call-back method.

Comment: Because garbage collection will not call your destroy method... and a destroy method normally contains "cleanup code" that you want to see executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `bean` declaration for the `engine`

```
<bean class="com.semanticbits.shoaib.innerbeans.Engine" destroy-method="destroy" init-method="init">
</bean>
```

This means Spring has a reference to this bean definition and to the instance it creates (which it injects). When you decide to close/shutdown the `ApplicationContext`, Spring goes through each bean and, if required, invokes their `destroy-method`.

You, however, are only destroying the `car` bean. The lifecycle of the `engine` bean is not tied to the `car` bean. The `engine` bean is part of the `ApplicationContext` even if it was defined within another `bean` definition.

Comment: So can you tell me now if I call context.getBeanFactory().destroySingletons(); after all the code I have written above then what should be output.

Comment: In addition to above output it is giving Car destroy method Engine Destroy method...Why car destroyed again if Car is already destroyed?

Comment: Please see my updated code. It is quite confusion once Car bean is destroyed then why again destroy method is called.

Comment: @shoaib The `destroyBean` method is meant to be used with prototype beans which the context no longer has any reference to. Try calling `destroySingletons` twice. After the first call, the context gets rid of all reference to the beans it has.

Comment: I read the doc which says that destroyBean(): usually a prototype instance is obtain from factory and destroy. Then do you think we have   two instance created for car one prototype and one singleton.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate No, the bean definition for `Car` makes it a singletong. However, the `destroyBean` method does not get rid of the reference to that instance from the `ApplicationContext`, specifically because the method is meant to be used with prototype beans for which the `ApplicationContext` does not have any reference. The method is just meant to call the `destroy-method` .